# Why does FastAPI ApiKeyHeader raise starlette.HTTPException instead of fastapi.HTTPException?

Tags: fastapi

(This question is less of a question and more of a navigation buoy for others)

fastapi defines a `HTTPException` exception that extends `starlette.HTTPException`.

The fastapi version is used in, for example, `HTTPBearer` authorization to denote when an expired token is presented.

However, in the sibling `ApiKeyHeader` authorization the `starlette.HTTPException` class is used.

I'm using both kinds of authentication in a service and it was confusing me why my `except HTTPException as e:` clause was being ignored for invalid API keys but not for invalid bearer authorizations until I stopped the code in the debugger in the `except Exception as e:` handler and asked for `type(e)`.

Consistency being the hobgoblin of little minds, my little mind is lost on the why of this. "It's a bug" is a valid answer, tbh, but I wasted a bit of time on this so maybe this question will help someone else through it.

(Update: I was about to create a PR to fix this and found this [PR](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/3703/files) from 2+ years ago that's now stale. This is probably a breaking API change and we want to use a little caution, but can we include this PR the next time we change the API)